# fixing cross domain tracking with GTM for an iframe - with no flicker?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have a page "Outer" with GA + GTM installed. Further down the page is an IFrame in which there is a page Inner from a different domain with the same GA + GTM where user's convert.

Both pages have auto linking setup the Iframe's src atribute has not been decorated via using the decorate() method and so the sessions break.

I'd like to add the missing decoration using GTM, without the content of the frame flickering. How I can intercept the dom event for the Iframe being added to the DOM - so I decorate it before it loads?